# How to remove duplicate field $1

Tags: awk, duplicates

I'd like to delete the 1st field of a string with awk if it is identical to the 2nd field.

This works partially for me it removes all duplicate fields:

```
echo "IBM IBM Dell HP HP"|awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (!a[$i]++) printf("%s%s",$i,FS)}{printf("\n")}'
IBM Dell HP
```

But I only want to remove field $1 if it is identical to $2. Desired output: "IBM Dell HP HP"
I was playing with !seen[$1,$2]++ but I didn't find a solution yet to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`

```
$ echo "IBM IBM Dell HP HP"| awk '$1==$2 {sub(/[^ ]* /,"",$0)}1'
IBM Dell HP HP
```

Using `sed`

```
$ echo "IBM IBM Dell HP HP"| sed -E 's/^([^ ]* )(\1)/\1/'
IBM Dell HP HP
```

Answer (score 2):

> "to remove field $1 if it is identical to $2"

you can just clear the 1st field if condition is met:

```
$ echo "IBM IBM Dell HP HP"| awk '{ if($1 == $2) $1=""; print substr($0, 2) }'
IBM Dell HP HP
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this, unsetting the first field if the 1st and the 2th are same:

```
echo $(echo "IBM IBM Dell HP HP" | awk '$1==$2{$1=""}1')
```

The `$( )` is there to take advantage of *word splitting* in `bash`, that remove the leading space on the output.

### Output

```
IBM Dell HP HP
```